# DOM not refreshed in React

Tags: reactjs, routes, navigation

My React app has three routes:

```
- R1: <Route exact path = "/" component = {Home} />
- R2: <Route exact path = "/ applicationsResp" component = {ApplicationsResp} />
- R3: <Route exact path = "/ missingResp" component = {ApplicationsResp} />
```

At launch, the Home component is displayed. The problem then comes.

I have two different entries in the menu :

```
"Consultation"
  "Applications Resp."
=> which points to R2
"Anomalies"
  "Application with missing responsibility"
=> which points to R3
```

I click on "Consultation / Applications Resp." and the list is displayed correctly.
If then I click on "Anomalies / Application with missing responsibility", the display does not change when it should since the list is no longer the same (a filter has been applied).
I have to refresh the page manually (with F5) to see the right information.
And of course, the behavior is identical if first click on "Anomalies / Application with missing responsibility" and then on "Consultation / Applications Resp."

Even if the same component is used, it is used with two different lists. So I expected React to refresh the DOM...

Did I miss something ?

Here's the code (pruned irrelevant lines to make it shorter).

in App.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
import "./App.css";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

import MyRoutes from "./components/routes";
import MyLink from "./components/link";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div className="navbar navbar-expand-sm sticky-top app-header charte-graphique-sg double-border">
          <a className="navbar-brand" href="/">
            <img
              src={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/images/soc102c.png`}
              height="30em"
              className="d-inline-block align-top"
              alt="logo Société Générale"
            />
          </a>
          <button
            className="navbar-toggler"
            type="button"
            data-toggle="collapse"
            data-target="#navbarToggler"
            aria-controls="navbarToggler"
            aria-expanded="false"
            aria-label="Toggle navigation"
          >
            <div className="navbar-toggler-icon logo-menu">==</div>
          </button>
          <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarToggler">
            <div>KPI Transformation</div>
            <ul className="navbar-nav nav-pills">
              <li className="nav-item dropdown">
                <a
                  className="nav-link dropdown-toggle"
                  href="#1"
                  data-toggle="dropdown"
                >
                  Consultation
                </a>
                <div className="dropdown-menu">
                  <MyLink nom="Applications Resp." vers="/applicationsResp" />
                </div>
              </li>
              <li className="nav-item dropdown">
                <a
                  className="nav-link dropdown-toggle"
                  href="#2"
                  data-toggle="dropdown"
                >
                  Anomalies
                </a>
                <div className="dropdown-menu">
                  <MyLink
                    nom="Application avec responsabilité manquante"
                    vers="/respManquantes"
                  />
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>

        <MyRoutes />
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

in routes.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

import Home from "./home";
import ApplicationsResp from "../containers/applicationsResp";

const MyRoutes = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
                {/* menu Consultation */}
                <Route exact path="/applicationsResp" component={ApplicationsResp} />
                {/* menu Anomalies */}
                <Route exact path="/respManquantes" component={ApplicationsResp} />
            </Switch>
        </div>
    );
};

export default MyRoutes;
```

in applicationResp.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

import BandeauTitre from "../components/bandeau-titre";

export default class ApplicationsResp extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      chemin: props.match.path,
      appli: [],
      nbItems: 0,
      titreBandeau: "",
      nbCellulesVides: 0,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:4000" + this.state.chemin)
      .then((response) => {
        this.setState({ appli: response.data });
        this.setState({ nbItems: response.data.length });
        // appel fx pour compter le nombre d'infos manquantes
        const vides = this.compteCellulesVides();
        this.setState({ nbCellulesVides: vides });

        let applications = `${this.state.nbItems} application${
          this.state.nbItems > 1 ? "s" : ""
        }`;
        let infos = "";
        infos =
          this.state.chemin === "/respManquantes"
            ? `, ${this.state.nbCellulesVides} info${
                this.state.nbCellulesVides > 1 ? "s" : ""
              } manquante${this.state.nbCellulesVides > 1 ? "s" : ""}`
            : "";
        // afficher infos seulement si appel depuis le menu Anomalies/Application avec responsablité manquante
        this.setState({
          titreBandeau: `Applications et leurs responsabilités ( ${applications} ${infos} )`,
        });
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container-fluid">
        <BandeauTitre titre={this.state.titreBandeau} />
        <table className="table table-striped">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Id</th>
              <th>Global_id</th>
              <th>Nom</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>{this.appliList()}</tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: if you have an API, then you need to make sure the  API is fetched again. Also please share your code, ex. the piece that how you wired with three routes and especially page 2 code.

Comment: Thanks for guiding me for my first post here. :-)

Comment: @Kobaya You have `<Route ...>` components in both app.js and router.js. Ideally you must have a menu component (like `<Link/>`) which redirects to the corresponding URL.
Use https://codesandbox.io/s/r0wxp0njw as an example

Comment: @Karthick Vinod I had put wrong code. It's now corrected thanks to you